# Does anyone know an example of a local homeomorphism from the open unit disc onto itself that is not a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I am interested in an example of a local homeomorphism from the open unit disc D onto itself
which is not a homeomorphism. Or, could one prove that any such map is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Use that the disc is simply connected and locally compact. If $a\ne b$ with $f(a)=f(b)$, a path from $a$ to $b$ gives a closed path from/to $f(a)$. This can be contracteded to the point $f(a)$. In the preimage this results in a path from $a$ to $b$ that is constant!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Actually, such maps abound since they are not required to be covering maps/proper.

Comment: Still not sure...is there a local homeomorphism from D onto D/

Comment: Is there a surjective immersion from R onto R?

Comment: Hagen : your proof sounds good...you are taking the preimage of the homotopy to get a constant path. It would seem this is where

Comment: local compactness is needed. The proof also seems to say that

Comment: any surjective immersion of R^2 to R^2 is a diffeo.

Comment: @DanGallo $f(z) =  \int_0^z \exp(z^2)\,dz$ is a surjective immersion of $\mathbb C$ to itself. (Surjectivity follows from Picard, because the function is odd; immersion because $f'$ never vanishes).

Comment: For more details see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147110/surjective-entire-functions-without-critical-points